# AWS Security Groups -- Name vs. Group Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS Security Groups, what is the difference between "Name" and "Group Name"?  It's confusing because when one creates a "Security Group", "Name" would seem to be interpreted as "name of the security group"...but then there is "Group Name".  Seems redundant to the point of confusion.  "Group Name" seems to be the more substantive and important field.

The "Name" field can be changed by clicking the pencil icon as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

But the "Group Name" cannot be edited and can be specified only at the time of creation:

[image]

I've been simply setting Name to be the same as Group Name for consistency and simplicity.  I can't find any guidance on best practices for the "Name" field and how or if it should be named relative to the "Group Name" field (the pop-up help on AWS simply describes required naming syntax).  Is "Name" just a convenience field which has little to zero significance (since it can be easily changed at any point)?  What are the programmatic and functional effects of these names?

Comment: There is also a Group Id.  Why have a Group Name and a Group ID? It seems that both uniquely identifies the Security Group.  Are there other types of AWS resources that have a similar structure?

Answer (score 32):

`Name` is simply displaying the value of the **`Name` tag** on the security group.

The *real* name is the **Group Name**, which cannot be changed after creation.

Yes, it is confusing!

Comment: the weird thing is that while "security group name" is that _actual_ name, in the AWS UI the _only_ columns you cannot hide are "Name" and "ID".